# How to make OverlayFS with multiple upperdirs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, overlay

I have the following directories:

```
/var/steamcmd
/var/servers/1/custom
/var/servers/2/custom
/var/servers/3/custom
... there could be many directories like this, not just 3.
```

My goal is to make the directory `steamcmd` the base, and for each `custom` directory I want the files to be merged with the base, so if there is a file in both `custom` and `steamcmd` then `custom` will be prioritized.

In order to do so I decided first to focus on one directory (`/var/servers/1/...`) and created another 2 directories, so my directories are:

```
/var/steamcmd ---------------> lowerdir
/var/servers/1/custom -------> upperdir
/var/servers/1/overlayWork --> work directory
/var/servers/1/steamcmd -----> the merged folder
```

I came up with this command, but with no success:

```
$ mount -t overlay -o \
lowerdir=/var/steamcmd,\
upperdir=/var/servers/1/custom,\
workdir=/var/servers/1/overlayWork \
/var/servers/1/steamcmd
```

I'm getting the following error when executing:

> mount: /var/servers/1/steamcmd: can't find in /etc/fstab.

How do I fix this? and can I make this work with multiple directories like presented above? (`/var/servers/{X}/custom`)

Comment: You need `overlay` as the first positional parameter, as in `mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=/var/steamcmd,upperdir=/var/servers/1/custom,workdir=/var/servers/1/overlayWork overlay /var/servers/1/steamcmd`. The extra `overlay` can also precede the `-o`.

Comment: I'll make it an answer, so others can see that it's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `overlay` as the first positional parameter, as in:

```
mount -t overlay \
-o lowerdir=/var/steamcmd,\
upperdir=/var/servers/1/custom,\
workdir=/var/servers/1/overlayWork \
overlay /var/servers/1/steamcmd
#^^^^^#
```

The extra `overlay` can also precede the `-o`:

```
                 #vvvvv#
mount -t overlay overlay \
-o lowerdir=/var/steamcmd,\
upperdir=/var/servers/1/custom,\
workdir=/var/servers/1/overlayWork \
/var/servers/1/steamcmd
```

Without this positional parameter, `mount` will assume that its options are defined in `/etc/fstab`; hence your error message.